# .net core encryption: Share secret key between worker process and client

Tags: c#, security, encryption, .net-core

I have a worker process in a virtual machine which must process files sent by clients, and store the results in a database. We do not want this virtual machine (and thus, the worker process) to directly face the Internet. Clients send those files to an intermediate cloud storage, and later the worker processes them in batch, when there are several of them. That means the files could be in the cloud storage during an undetermined amount of time. One of my requirements is that **the files must be encrypted while at rest** in this storage. We are using the storage as a service, we do not have control over it (and other requirement is that we should not be bound to a cloud provider, so **cloud provider specific solution won't do the job)**.

The approach we want to follow is to encrypt them in the client using a key shared with the worker process (symmetric encryption). They will be encrypted until the worker process picks them up from the storage and decrypts them using the shared key.

We want to use [.Net Core 2.0 data protect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/) framework both on the client and the virtual machine, and we need to share the key between this worker process and clients. Reading through the docs, I've seen we can use a Redis key storage provider, but I understand the use case for that is to share the key between different app servers. Also, I am not sure storing the keys in an Internet facing Redis instance is a good idea (because that increases the attack surface).

So, the question is, **how can I share the data protect framework generated keys between worker process and client securely?**.

Note: there is also another component, a web server, that will face the Internet and will have direct communication with the virtual machine, but this virtual machine won't directly face the Internet for the aforementioned reasons. We may use this web server to communicate the worker process and the clients, but not sure if there is a better approach.

Comment: have your server send it to the storage system. keep the key private. or have the client upload with their private key and they give you the public key to decrypt it.

Comment: Sorry, I see I have not explained it well, the point is exactly to avoid processing the file in the server in first place. Let me edit the question, so the use case is properly explained.

Comment: many cloud services allow you to store files at rest with their own encryption layers that's transparent.

Comment: @DanielA.White "other requirement is that we should not be bound to a cloud provider, so cloud provider specific solution won't do the job"

Comment: If possible - it would be good to generate new encryption key for each file you upload to cloud service and then send that file-specific key to your service (together with information about file that was encrypted). That way you don't have to store key on client, which might be a weak point. And I'd agree that using AES or other algorithm directly will be easier than data protection api in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're overcomplicating the issue. Unless encrypting the files on the client is a requirement (you didn't say so), you don't have to.

Send the files from the client to the server over HTTPS, encrypt them on the server, and then send them to the storage.

This way, you don't need to share anything, the server will control the entire process, and you have the option to save the encryption key in any way you want.

If encrypting the files on the client is a requirement, then encrypt them on the client, send them to the server, send the encryption key to the server over HTTPS, store the key on the server in any way you want, and then send them to the storage.

Note: I don't think that the .NET Core Data Protection is the best choice for your scenario. It's much easier to simply use the AES encryption directly.

Comment: "It's much easier to simply use the AES encryption directly." Why? Looking through the data protect API, it seems very straightforward to use. Maybe I am missing something.

Comment: That's the exact problem, it was designed to be very easy to use and hide most details from you. You'll have to figure out how to share the key with the server. It's not designed for that scenario, it's goal is to protect info on the server. Using AES directly, you don't need to figure out anything. You encrypt using a key and salt, and then send them to the server. The time you need to learn the Data Protection API is more than the time you need to actually implement it with AES.

Comment: You have convinced me. It is easier that way. Also, I like the throw away key idea from [@Evk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5311735/evk). Thanks for your help.

Comment: @RacilHilan I agree with your answer but please don't call an IV a salt.  It is not a salt.  It is completely different.